# Is there a word for a literary technique that allows a short passage to be read aloud in more than one way?

Tags: terminology, literary-device

I recently started reading Sam Logan's [*Sam and Fuzzy*](http://www.samandfuzzy.com/) online, and am greatly enjoying it.

In the fifth volume of the NMS Series (*Sam and Fuzzy Missing Inaction*, "[Boundaries, Pt. 9](http://Boundaries,%20Pt.%209)") there's a cute scene where Sam references the [Hokey Pokey](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokey_cokey), and two other characters finish the traditional verse.

> [image]
>
> Sam: You've got it all wrong. I'm just doing what **you** all do. You
>   put the right bribes in. You take the right guys out. Y'know. The
>   crime Hokey Pokey.
>
> Paxton: You're just trying to turn this all around.
>
> Tusks: **THAT'S WHAT IT'S ALL ABOUT!** (*slams hand on table with a
>   WHAM!*)

Now, there are two ways to read this exchange, if one were to read it aloud, with stressing and inflection. You can read it as a normal verbal exchange, and ignore the song -- then Tusks is shouting, after having just understood Sam's true intentions. However, you can also read it (as I suspect most people would) with the inflection and tones (and probably even music!) that belong to the song, up to and including the "WHAM" at the end. This leads to a curious (and fun!) effect.

**Is there a term for a passage like this one, that deliberately messes with the way that a reader will form the words in their mind?**

"[Double entendre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_entendre)" crossed my mind, but that effect is one of meaning, not inflection.

Comment: As far as I know there isn't. I wrote a short short story (published here: http://monkeybicycle.net/oss102115/ ) that was intentionally designed to be only readable on the page courtesy of the final punctuation which changes the reader's expectation for the meaning of the piece.